# Endless Corridor in Unity – Vector 3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some trouble to find a solution for this: I have a Ball, which moves along a corridor. To create the Illusion, that the corridor is endless, the Ball gets teleported back at a certain point, to where the surrounding looks exactly the same as the teleporting point.

To do this, I need to change the X Position of the Ball, without changing it's current y or z position.

I tried:

```
if (transform.position.x <= -20) {
    transform.position = new Vector3(60, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

But this sets the ball back in y and z position, too.
Thanks for your time and greetings from germany :)

Comment: *"But this sets the ball back in y and z position, too."* Your code looks like. Is the ball a child of any object?

Comment: No, it's not a child. I don't know how to change only the x-coordinate, while the others don't change. Is there a way to substract 20x from a vector 3, while the other two values are not affected?

You may notice, I'm a c# beginner :) I hope you can help

Comment: @TobiasLorenz Are you SURE it's not a child? Sounds like it. Anyway to answer your question in the comments it would be transform.position -= new Vector3(20, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
if (transform.position.x <= -20) {
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.x + 20, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

This offsets the ball by exactly 20 units from where ever it was. If you want it to go further, modify the `+20` to a value that fits your scene.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I did before (just that I had a value for x already instead of doing an addition) 

It seems like transform.position.y and transform.position.z are setting the ball back to zero. But the current y and z position should not change :(

Comment: @TobiasLorenz what do you mean "setting the ball back to zero"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! You we're totally right. I just had to get the gameobject.
The solution:

```
if (gameObject.transform.position.x <= -20) {
    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (60, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
```

Comment: I doubt this answer and the one below it. `gameObject.transform` is the-same as `transform.position`. Something else is wrong with your code.